# is there is a faster way to include 300+ of ID numbers in where clause in Oracle SQL instead of writing them one by one?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I have to retrieve information for certain id numbers which are more than 300 numbers so I need to put all of them in the where clause as condition one by one which consume time. Is there a way or better solution to do that? using **Oracle SQL**

Comment: Why is that time-consuming? And what do you mean by  "one by one"? Do you run the queries one by one? You can use the `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,7)` pattern to do it in one query.

Comment: are they in a range and consecutive

Answer (score 2):

One way or another, you will need to enumerate those `id`s (the database cannot just guess them).

One convenient approach is to create a table to store the list of `id`s, where each `id` appears on a separate row. You can do that programmtically with the tool of your choice.

With this set up at hand, say table `numbers`, you can then use it in your query with a `join` or an `exists` subquery, like:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join numbers n on n.id = t.id
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from numbers n where n.id = t.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping , I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like, the answer to your question is `IN`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in ( . . . );
```

Oracle is smart enough to use an index in this case.  Note that Oracle limits the number of values in an explicit `in` list to 1,000.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know that there is a limit for `in`

Comment: There is no limit to the "in" list if it is the result of a subselct:  where t.id in (select list_id from number_list)